# Suite for pages in Fitnesse Java

Tags: java, fitnesse

Hi i am trying for Test suite pages in Fitnesse.so my page is look like below if i hit suite button it have to suite all link and want to produce result .if i run a paritcular page its working good with Test Page .How suite page works ??

my question is whether we have to create java class for suite page or it automatically import our package in setup it will suite page i read through page but i cant get idea kindly help on this http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.SuiteAcceptanceTests
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684735/how-to-include-all-ancestral-setup-pages-in-fitnesse-subwikis](http://stackoverflow%20link)

which SuiteAcceptanceTests i have to use??? for my scenario
what I understood is In Setup we have to import our package it wil take care depanding on Folder.
 My package is com.xx.xx

### Apple

```
a
b
c
```

---

### Ball

```
a
b
c
```

.....etc

Am Getting Error Like this

Test Summaries

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of method 'execute' in class fitnesse.responders.run.TestResponder$TestExecutor threw exception java.lang.StackOverflowError at suitePage.vm[line 23, column 15]
org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTMethod.handleInvocationException(ASTMethod.java:261)
org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:187)
org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:280)
org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.render(ASTReference.java:369)
org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode.render(SimpleNode.java:342)
org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Parse.render(Parse.java:260) org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTDirective.render(ASTDirective.java:207)
org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode.render(SimpleNode.java:342)
org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:356)
org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:260)
fitnesse.html.template.HtmlPage.render(HtmlPage.java:80)
fitnesse.responders.run.TestResponder.doSending(TestResponder.java:69)
fitnesse.responders.ChunkingResponder.startSending(ChunkingResponder.java:66)
fitnesse.http.ChunkedResponse.sendTo(ChunkedResponse.java:25)
fitnesse.FitNesseExpediter.sendResponse(FitNesseExpediter.java:94)
fitnesse.FitNesseExpediter.start(FitNesseExpediter.java:46)
fitnesse.FitNesseServer.serve(FitNesseServer.java:24)
fitnesse.FitNesseServer.serve(FitNesseServer.java:17)
fitnesse.socketservice.SocketService$ServerRunner.run(SocketService.java:99)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the exception stack trace, it looks pretty similar to the Github discussion [here](https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/issues/804).

A page that includes itself, for example, in the content.txt of page **.SuitePage.TestPage**, you have

`!include .SuitePage.TestPage`

This can cause the StackOverflowError you see. Check your `!includes` carefully and see whether it fixes your problem.

Comment: post more details if it does not fix your problem